# Turn a dictionary of dictionaries into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So let's say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{Row1 : {Col1: Data, Col2: Data ..} , Row2: {Col1: Data,...},...}
```

Ex dictionary:

```
{'1': {'0': '1', '1': '2', '2': '3'}, '2': {'0': '4', '1': '5', '2': '6'}}
```

I was checking out pandas from_dict method with orient='index', but it's not quite what I need.

This is what I have that works:

```
df_pasted_data = pd.DataFrame()
for v in dictionary.values():
    # need to set the index to 0 since im passing in a basic dictionary that looks like: col1: data, col2: data
    # otherwise it will throw an error saying  ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
    temp = pd.DataFrame(v, index=[0])
    # append doesn't happen in place so i need to set it to itself
    df_pasted_data = df_pasted_data.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

This works, but I've read online that doing appends and stuff is not very efficient, is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: this example returns same as `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary,orient='index')` can you show us how this doesnot work..?

Comment: oh wow you're right. That's mb, I should have prolly tested that before trying my own way. I just assumed it wouldn't work since it didn't adhere to the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of `DataFrame()` method and `T`(Transpose) attribute:

```
import pandas as pd
df_pasted_data=pd.DataFrame(dictionary).T

#output
print(df_pasted_data)
    0   1   2
1   1   2   3
2   4   5   6
```